# Mathematica if condition

Tags: if-statement, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to do an if statement to test whether the variable m is equal to game1 or game2 and if it is show it as a two move game and if its game3 or game4 show it as a one move game.

```
 game1 = Image[]
 game2 = Image[]
 game3 = Image[]
 game4 = Image[]
```

The above 4 variables are assigned to 4 different images.

```
 m := RandomChoice[{game1, game2, game3, game4}];

 If[m === game1 || game2 , InputString["This is a two move game"], 
 InputString["This is a one move game"]]
```

This is totally failing. the 4 game variables are assigned to images and we need to show the image and have a input box pop up

This is another alternative I came up with that also failed.

```
 m := RandomChoice[{game1, game2, game3, game4}];
If[m == game1 || game2 , InputString["This is a two move game"]];
If[m == game3 || game4 , InputString["This is a one move game"]]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use this syntax: `m === game1 || game2`

For example instead of `1 == 2 || 3` you should use `1 == 2 || 1 == 3`

However, you are using `m` multiple times, and each time it is used it will change.  So you need to fix `m`, e.g.

```
m := RandomChoice[{game1, game2, game3, game4}];
a = m;
If[a == game1 || a == game2 , InputString["This is a two move game"]];
If[a == game3 || a == game4 , InputString["This is a one move game"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
moves01 = Thread[{game3, game4} -> "one move game"]
moves02 = Thread[{game1, game2} -> "two move game"]
moves = Association@Catenate[{moves01, moves02}]
m := RandomChoice[{game1, game2, game3, game4}];
moves[m]
```